# Menu de jQuery para javaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar um `toogle` no menu em `media query`, mas quero em JavaScript puro, pois estou tentando não utilizar jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.menu').click(function(){
         $('nav').toggleClass('active'); 
      })
    });
```

Como converter esse em jQuery para JS puro?

Comment: Olá, eu estou tentando buscar a maneira correta para aplicar, preciso ativar uma classe CSS oculta dentro de uma Tag HTML só que já tentei com Toogle e não foi, eu quero realmente aprender o conceito em JS. Estou tentando aplicar para fins de estudos.

Answer (score 1):

Convertendo o seu código para JS puro ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
(function() {

      const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
      const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

      menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.nav.classList.toggle('active');
      });
})();
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar aplicar aqui.